# PhpStorm 2016.3 - Default terminal settings

Tags: phpstorm

How to set default terminal settings in PhpStorm for all future projects? All I can do, is to modify path only for currently opened project and the default value for *"Shell path"* is `cmd.exe` which I don't want to use.

*[Windows 10]*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change `Shell Path` with your desired terminal path in `Tools -> Terminal`, then `apply` and `ok`. This settings change will work for all of your future projects in phpStorm.

Comment: Nope. It won't. I've tested it. As you can see in the breadcrumb, these options are saved only for current project :(.

Answer (score 1):

`File | Default Settings...` -- options set there affect future new projects (they do not affect already existing projects in any way).

Also --- try latest **2016.3.1 [EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program)** -- it contains changes from these tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157148
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163474